# Playonlinux will not work

Tags: playonlinux

I've installed Playonlinux on my computer but I will not start, the icon will light up but that's it.  When I try to start the message

```
Looking for python... 2.7.6 - selected    
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.2.5) is starting    
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory    
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 32bits direct rendering is enabled    
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 64bits direct rendering is enabled    
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/a/.PlayOnLinux/    
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible    
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: Capture...    
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: ScreenCap...    
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: PlayOnLinux Vault...    
[maj_check] Message: List is up to date
```

I've just got a linux machine and I'm learning as I go so if you feel like commenting please go into as much detail as possible.

Comment: I don't see any errors, is that all of the output that `playonlinux` gives when run from the terminal?